# Assistance with conditional formatting rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to set up two rules; 1 that will change the fill color on adjacent cells within that row and the other to tally the counts onto another tab for totals.

1. I have a total 8 columns with a rule set up in column H to change to the appropriate color based on the text entered. How do I get the other cells within that row to change to the same color?
2. Based on the text in column H, how can I move the counts in my Totals tab? 4 columns in the totals tab; total claims assigned, other, follow up, and completed?

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/723Wj.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nUDn.jpg)

Comment: Can you give a sample of data? A screenshot of dummy data, perhaps?

Comment: @Vylix - Please see edit

Comment: What is the expected result? What "counts" ? Activity counts? Folder moved to counts?

Comment: It will be based off of the counts in Folder moved.

Comment: I mean, where the count formula will be put on? `I` column? What do you expect of the format of the result? Some kind of table?

Comment: I just added a 2nd screenshot of my totals tab. So I have each of my direct reports working off the spreadsheet, each with their own tab, that looks like the first screenshot I sent you. So if a it results in a "follow up" how can I get that to tally up to the totals tab without manual entering it

Comment: As proposed by @teylyn, this question should be split into new question. You can ask another question (and put link to this question so we know it's connected), and ask the second question there.

Answer (score 0):

Re 1: Use conditional formatting with a formula. Select A1 to G1, create a new rule that uses a formula and use a formula that has an absolute reference to column H, like this

```
=$H1="something"
```

Then set a format for that rule. Repeat for other text values that you may have in column H.

Re 2: Not enough information to answer that. Split it out into a new question and post a data sample, along with expected results and logic explained in words.